# How to correctly modularize a node.js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, modularity

I'm creating a node.js project following the class constructor pattern:

```
function my_class(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

The starting point of the project is the `main.js` file. Any class of the project must be able to access global objects (such as "world" and "socket") which are defined on `main.js`. I found 4 options:

1. I define my classes inside `main.js`. They'll have access to `main.js`'s globals for being on it's closure, but `main.js` will become bloated.
2. I move the class to another file such as `my_class.js` and `require()` it. This doesn't work because my_class's instances will lose the closure context and no longer be able to access `main.js`'s globals.
3. I move the class to another file and manually inject dependencies to it's constructor (ex: `my_class(world,socket)`). The problem is, code becomes much more complicated and weird semantics such as "my_instance.world" pop on the source, which is nonsense because "world" is not property of `my_class`.
4. I move the class to another file and require it using `my_class = eval(fs.readFileSync(())` instead of `require`. This works just fine as my_class gets `main.js`'s closure context, and is the solution I'm using, but seems hacky.

Which is the right way to modularize such node.js project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems tricky because **you have a circular dependency**: `main.js` depends on the functionality of `my_class` and `my_class` depends on the data of `main.js`.

By putting the data of `main.js` into the `global` object you resolve the circular dependency:

- `main.js` depends on the functionality of `my_class.js`
- `main.js` depends on the data in the `global` object
- `my_class.js` depends on the data in the `global` object

Now, to get rid of putting the data into the `global` object, implement a third module in let us say `data.js`. Then you require the sources like this:

- `main.js` requires `data.js`
- `main.js` requires `my_class.js`
- `my_class.js` requires `data.js`

Since modules in node.js are singletons both `main.js` and `my_class.js` will get the same instance of `data.js`.

Comment: How did you find this 1 year after?

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly the possible solution:

main.js:

```
(function(){
  var global = "test"; // this you wanna have as a closure

  var my_class = require('./my_class')(global);
  my_class.go();
})();
```

my_class.js:

```
module.exports = function(global){
  return {
    go: function(){
      console.log(global);
    }
  };
};
```

So it's similar to your 3. option

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make variables in main.js available anywhere, then you can assign properties to the `global` object. See node.js global variables? for example. It would work fine as long as you don't over do it. With Neo's solution, you gain a little more flexibility for example with testing, because you can "inject" an arbitrary object into the module. Not every module has to use the same "global" per se.